# I'm having problems adding the computer to the domain, domain filed is non-selectable

Tags: active-directory, windows-8

I'm trying to add my computer to my domain, but when I go to the system properties I cant enter domain in the Member of section. The Workgroup however is up and running... why cant i switch to domain?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Windows 8?  Some versions (as with Win 7 and others) are not able to join a domain.  Windows 8 Pro will join as will enterprise.

[Comparison Chart of features/Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions#Comparison_chart).

Comment: You are spot on. I cant. Downloaded the wrong image of msdn. but now as i see domain aint supported on windows 8 rt im putting it aside as i thought i could make that sexy sweet sync between all my devices thru AD. :-(

Comment: Can you mark as answer?

Comment: done, thought i did tho :D